# How to obtain spatial density from material density?

Tags: integration, density, continuum-mechanics

When you introduce the concept of the spatial density of an extensive property, a question of change of variables arises. Assume $\Omega$ is an extensive property, and $\omega$ and $\rho$ are its density and spatial density respectively. Also, according to continuum terminology, assume $p$ is a particle and $\chi$
maps a particle onto a point in space at any specific time.

**Now the question**:

How to obtain the equality below
$$
\int\omega\mathrm{d}p=\int\int\int\rho \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z
$$
where $\rho=\rho(x,y,z,t,\chi)$?

*P.S.:Assume that $p=\chi^{-1}(x,y,z,t)$ is an invertible real-valued function, where $x,y$ and $z$ are real scalars and $t$ is time. Also assume that the inverse of $p$ is a vector-valued function, $(x,y,z)=\chi(p,t)$. In addition, assume $\omega=\omega(p,t,\chi)$ is a real-valued function, and $\Omega=\int\omega \mathrm{d}p$.*

Comment: If I understand correctly:
(i) $\mathrm dp$ and $\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$ are both elementary volumes, the former defined on the initial (material) configuration and the latter defined on the current (spatial) configuration.
And (ii) $\omega$ and $\rho$ are mass densities measured in kg/m3.

If so then **the equality you wrote is the principle of mass conservation**.
It is a requirement to model physical systems, but it is postulated as such and so there is no mathematical trickery to connect the left hand side to the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: @neerby By $p$ I mean particle labels. Using particle coordinates in the initial configuration is just our choice; another possibility is that $p$ is a real number (this is the case in my question), i.e., particles are labeled by real numbers.

Comment: I think i see better, thank you. Does the mass conservation explanation make sense to you or is there some deeper understanding to look for?

Comment: @neerby Yes, it makes sense, I was wondering if there is a way to reach the RHS from the LHS by a change of variables when $p$ a real valued particle label (so, $\mathrm{d}p$ is not a volume element.)